# Search for exact match of a line

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I would like to find in a set of files the exact mach of a line `hello world`. For instance, let's say `test1.txt` and `test2.txt` are all the `.txt` in the folder, and `test1.txt` is:

```
hello world
a hello world
```

and `test2.txt` is:

```
hello world b
helloworld
hello world
hello world
```

I would expect `3` as return for `hello world`. But what I know is `grep -l "hello world" *.txt | wc -l`, which doesn't work well.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -Fcx 'hello world'
```

should do it. For multiple input files, use

```
cat *.txt | grep -Fcx 'hello world'
```

This way, the `cat` combines the files into one input stream for `grep`, providing a global count.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that I want to look for in a set of files, updated my OP...

Comment: it gives me `bash: *.*: ambiguous redirect`

Comment: @SoftTimur: Ugh, indeed. A redirection `< *.txt` works in zsh, but not in bash. Fixed.

Comment: @SoftTimur I usually test, although you caught me being sloppy using the zsh. :) Well, you need to feed it the right files. Make sure that, if you are using the `*.txt` pattern or similar, you are in the right directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -x -c "hello world" test.txt
```

that will give you 2 as a result.

and if you want to know what lines your hits can be found on, you can use

```
grep -n -x "hello world" test.txt
```

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that I want to look for in a set of files, updated my OP...

Answer (score 0):

`grep` is generally the best and fastest tool for this, but for the record, if you want a pure bash method, you could do:

```
$ { c=0; while IFS='' read -r line; do [ "$line" = "hello world" ] && ((c++)); done; echo $c; } < test.txt 
2
$
```

---

A comment asks *"Why unset `IFS`?"*.  Consider what happens if we have whitespace at the beginning or end of a line (I assume from the question, we want an exact match, so the extra whitespace should cause the match to fail):

```
$ echo " hello world" | { c=0; while read -r line; do [ "$line" = "hello world" ] && ((c++)); done; echo $c; }
1
$ echo " hello world" | { c=0; while IFS='' read -r line; do [ "$line" = "hello world" ] && ((c++)); done; echo $c; }
0
$
```

If IFS is set, then `read` will split the line according to IFS and then assign the resulting tokens to variables.  Since we have whitespace at the beginning, then this is treated as a separator and is effectively discarded.

---

In fact if we use the builtin variable `$REPLY`, we don't need to worry about `IFS` at all.  So:

```
{ c=0; while read -r; do [ "$REPLY" = "hello world" ] && ((c++)); done; echo $c; } < test.txt
```

Comment: Why unset `IFS`? Otherwise, nice effort :)

Answer (score 0):

grep has the special characters '^' to match the beginning of the line, and '$' to match the end, so if you do:

grep "^hello world$" *.txt

You will get the lines you are looking for, and you can add a "| wc -l" for the count, or concatenate the lines and use the -c option to grep (as someone above suggested).

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name "you want file patterns" | xargs grep -x "hello world" | wc -l
```

In your situation, the desired command is:

```
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs grep -x "hello world" | wc -l
```